# Multiple Select Dropdown With No Jquery or Bootstrap Plugin(Core Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anybody know how to create multi-select dropdown like this?:

[image]

```html
<select name="city" id="mySelect">
  <!-- <option value="select"> </option> -->
  <option value="banglore">Banglore</option>
  <option value="bhubaneswar">Bhubaneswar</option>
  <option value="patna">Patna</option>
  <option value="indore">Indore</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _"Does anybody know how to create multi-select dropdown like this?"_ - the authors of the plugins/libraries you mentioned in the title probably do. Which means, you could look at what they did, instead of asking us to more or less write a tutorial for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a div with your list and checkboxes. They can be made visible using the :focus-within in CSS. A multiselect droptown doesn't exists in native HTML as far as I know

```
<div with focus-within>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="city" value="val1">Val1</li>
...
</li>
</div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/keeping-parent-visible-child-focus/
This should explain it.
Also you can remove the dot in the list using CSS